# How to style a custom HTML element based on child node selector(s), using a shadow DOM attached stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I have a custom HTML element which may group `button` elements:

```html
<custom-element>
    <button>Foo</button>
    <button>Bar</button>
    <button>Baz</button>
</custom-element>
```

I link a stylesheet to the element using the `adoptedStylesheets` property on the shadow root (`shadowRoot` property on the element, in the "open" mode).

The `button`'s are "slotted" (assigned to `slot` elements I have in the shadow tree).

I have a "prompt" element in the shadow tree of the custom element:

```html
<span class="prompt">Use one of the following button(s)</span>
```

I'd like to toggle displaying of the above element based on whether all of the `button` element children of their `custom-element` parent have each their `hidden` attribute set or not -- if *all* button(s) are thus hidden, prompt shall not be displayed (`display: none`), otherwise it shall be (`display: revert`).

Hiding `.prompt` by default -- assuming there are only `hidden` buttons, was easy:

```css
.prompt { display: none; }
```

I am unable, however, to come up with a selector that will do the opposite -- show `.prompt` when at least one `button` is not `hidden` (inverse condition of "all buttons are hidden").

I've tried a number of selector permutations, but none seem to do what I want:

```css
:host(:has(::slotted(button:not([hidden])))) .prompt {
    display: revert;
}
```

```css
:host(:has(button:not([hidden]))) .prompt {
    display: revert;
}
```

```css
:host(:has(::slotted(button:not([hidden])))) .prompt {
    display: revert;
}
```

Is it even possible to select a descendant of the custom element along a branch of the shadow tree, based on a predicate applying to the custom element along the light DOM tree, specifically one like "contains `button` children that do not feature the `hidden` attribute"?

The problem seems to lie in the `:has` selector -- I am unable to use `:host(:has(...))` for any `...`. I have seen mention that `:host` is *featureless*, yet `:host .prompt` works as expected, for example, so I am further confused about exactly which features whatever is selected by `:host` or `:host(...)`, has.

Anyway, I am curious as to my immediate practical problem -- is CSS alone able to pull this off? Otherwise I am using `ResizeObserver` to respond to changes in the element's bounding box, taking these as indirect signs of toggling of `hidden` attribute on the buttons. Its not a bad alternative, but ideally I'd like CSS alone to do this.

I have half a month old Firefox, Edge and Chrome releases I have been testing with.

Answer (score 1):

`:host` (inside shadowDOM) selects the element itself, `:host .prompt` selects elements **inside** shadowDOM

`:host(x)` selects **attributes on** the element

You will not get to your buttons (in lightDOM) there

I am no CSS guru, don't think it can be done with CSS
**+** matches 2 siblings, you can't match 3?

Isn't it easier to have the element register *one* click handler on itself and query over the 3 buttons, setting an attribute on the element so CSS in shadowDOM can be used

##### My interpretation

`button + button` can only select two elements

`button + button + button` does not work

So you have to always check the state of your buttons:

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("three-buttons", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode: "open"})
        .innerHTML = `<style>`+
        `:host { padding:1em }` +
        `:host([three]){background:green}`+
        `::slotted([hidden]) { background: red; display: revert }` +
        `</style><slot/>`;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // wait till buttons are parsed
        this.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          let btn = e.target;
          if (btn.id == "reset") {
            this.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(b =>  b.hidden = false);
          } else {
            btn.hidden = !btn.hidden;
            let hiddenbuttons = this.querySelectorAll("button[hidden]");
            this.toggleAttribute("three", hiddenbuttons.length == 3);
          }
        });
      })
    }
  });
</script>
<three-buttons>
  <button>b1</button><button>b2</button>
  <button>b3</button><button>b4</button>
  <button id="reset">reset</button>
</three-buttons>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your statements that attempt to explain the nature of `:host`. However, let me clarify that I _can_ get to the buttons using e.g. the `::slotted(button)` pseudo-element, for one. Furthermore, I am not sure what you meant with the "2 siblings, you can't match 3"? And, what does handling of `click` events have to do with this? I need to toggle displaying of the `.prompt` based on a function of the set of buttons, specifically the `hidden` attribute on each, not depending on an event, much less the "click" event. But still, I am getting convinced CSS won't be enough.

Comment: I added code. Minor bug with the background color

Comment: Thank you for showing what you meant. The problem with your "click"-driven code is, again, that it, unfortunately, doesn't solve my problem. The buttons I slot within my shadow root, originate and remain as children of the custom element in the light DOM tree, and _anything_ is allowed in principle to modify their `hidden` attribute -- since they're part of the document tree, they're ultimately owned by the document, not just the custom element that contains them. Hence my trying to design the behaviour using changing of `hidden` attribute as trigger, _not_ triggering the changes myself.

Comment: Now I understand your ``ResizeObserver`` (and not ``MutationObserver`` (which should catch your ``hidden`` workaround??) in you question, yes you need that one to (hopefully) catch _"anything"_ changes.

Comment: To elaborate, `MutationObserver` would work almost as well, I'd say -- unless I style buttons in a way that even when `hidden` these are displayed, or the other way around -- when not `hidden` they're not displayed. The component is reusable and ideally generic enough to allow and leave styling of buttons to document author, so `ResizeObserver` has an edge on `MutationObserver` here -- I don't need to care then what the value of the `hidden` is, assuming (wrongly, possibly) the corresponding button is shown/hidden, instead I just see if element has a rendered width, and act accordingly.

Comment: I did want to avoid accomplishing this through scripting though, hence my question. Since the matter boils down to whether to show parts of the custom element (shadow tree) depending on whether any of the contained buttons are effectively displayed, solving this strictly in the presentation layer with CSS alone would have been ideal indeed.

Comment: JS is probably the _easiest_ way. Is Una her bog post a CSS alternative? https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-logical-styling-based-on-the-number-of-given-elements/